# How to properly export Xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode

I edited an existing project in Xcode and added a folder in it. In that folder, I placed 2 folders. And created a cocoa touch class in both of them. Now, when I look in to the directory of my project. My classes are not inside the folder, where they're expected.

It should be located in

> Screens -> MyView -> View1 & View 2

But instead it is in the Screens folder

On Xcode, it is properly located but when I open the root folder of the project it isn't. How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Xcode itself does not create any folders for you on your mac. 
You have to create the folder structure manually on your mac. Then move the files to the new location.
Next delete them out of Xcode then drag and drop the files from your mac folder to the virtual folders within Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create folders manually in your project. Adding files to XCode group does not reflect to your project folder structure. Just remove reference of the existing files from your XCode and then move the required files into your desired folder and add them back to your XCode Project. Hope this will help you.